# Restore styling of sticky navbar

Tags: javascript, css

I am using wordpress to create a website. I was trying to generate a sticky navbar and was successful with following code:
--JS:

```
const nav = document.querySelector('#masthead');
let navTop = nav.offsetTop;
function fixedNav() {
if (window.scrollY >= navTop) {    
nav.classList.add('fixed');
} else {
nav.classList.remove('fixed');    
}}
window.addEventListener('scroll', fixedNav);
```

--CSS:

```
#masthead.fixed {
position: fixed;
box-shadow: 5px 5px 19px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#masthead.fixed ul li img {
height: 36px;
}
#masthead.fixed ul li a {
font-size: 14px;
}
```

The css applies to the navbar when the page is scrolled down and sticky function invokes.
Now the problem is when I return the webpage to its top the navbar should restore to its previous styling and the css that was applied after the scrolling should release its effect. How can I achieve that?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to leave only "greater" and remove "equals", because it means if scroll position greater **OR** equals 0, then apply **fixed** style.

Write it like that: `if (window.scrollY > navTop)`

Comment: Also I'd recommend to change let on const since you don't change the value.

Answer (score 1):

Just add an statement to check when the page is at the top:

```
else if (scrollY == 0) {
    nav.classList.remove('fixed')
}
```

Also I would recommend to add a boolean variable so the event doesn't fire all the time, something like this:

```
var ticking = false;

window.onscroll = function (e) {
  if (!ticking) {
    if (window.scrollY >= navTop) {
      nav.classList.add('fixed');
      ticking = true;
  } else if (scrollY == 0) {
    nav.classList.remove('fixed');
    ticking = false;
  }
```

Comment: Thank You for taking your time helping. The second code you suggested is being blocked by the WordPress Firewall.